# ArcGIS feature table SRID is NULL

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-10.5, srid

I am using Oracle to store ArcGIS data. I have created my table named `PARCELS` from ArcCatalog, and I inserted some data using ArcMap. So when I run the following SQL query: `select * from MDSYS.ALL_SDO_GEOM_METADATA;`

```
OWNER   TABLE_NAME   COLUMN_NAME   DIMINFO             SRID
MY_SCH  PARCELS      SHAPE         {{null, 12345.4,... NULL
```

In this stuation, I can not run transform queries. Why this issue is occurred? How can I fix this?

Comment: You need to provide more information about *how* you created the feature class. Note that the `sde` user should ***never*** own any user data (much the same as `SYSTEM` or `MDSYS`)

Comment: I updated question for schema. And what did you mean for question "how you created the feature class"? or How should I create?

Comment: How did you use ArcCatalog to create the feature class? What exact parameters did you provide? Also relevant is how you've configured the DBTUNE environment, since SDO_GEOMETRY is not the default storage type.